# How to install libpq-dev on Centos 5.5

Tags: centos, postgresql, yum

In order to develop one web application based on postgresql, i need to install libpq on my centos.

I can install it by "apt-get install libpq-dev" on ubuntu, but i can not install it on centos by "yum install libpq".

Who can tell me how to install it, thanks!

Answer (score 63, accepted):

The package is called `postgresql-libs` on Red Hat and derived distributions.

Comment: Usefull answer.so many answer tell me install libpq-dev!

Comment: `postgresql-libs` is the shared library.  However, `postgresql-devel` is the development code (equivalent to Debian's `libpg-dev`).

Comment: As mentioned, this is not the equivalent to libpq-dev. The correct answer is postgresql-devel.

Answer (score 94):

I just had to install this on my CentOS 6 server since psycopg2 required pg_config.  Boo yah:

```
yum install postgresql-devel
```

**Update**

If you still encounter issues with pg_config, you may need to add it to your PATH, e.g.:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/pgsql-x.x/bin
```

where x.x is your version, such as /usr/pgsql-9.2./bin.

Comment: This worked for me (I also needed pg_config to install psycopg2)

Comment: remember, if you are trying to do a global install (sudo pip install psycopg2) to add it to the right path. Wasn't working for me, even after supplying -`-install-option` with `pip install` and then I realized I was doing sudo pip install.

Answer (score 7):

It is `libpqxx`:

```
Name       : libpqxx-devel
Arch       : x86_64
Version    : 2.6.9
Release    : 3.el5.rf
Size       : 1.4 M
Repo       : rpmforge
Summary    : Header files, libraries and development documentation for libpqxx.
URL        : http://pqxx.org/
License    : BSD
Description: This package contains the header files, static libraries and development
           : documentation for libpqxx. If you like to develop programs using libpqxx,
           : you will need to install libpqxx-devel.
```

You can install it from [rpmforge](http://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories/RPMForge) or [epel](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) repo:

```
# yum install libpqxx-devel
```

Comment: No, that's a different package.

Comment: `xx` means `C++`.